# How do DNS record work

Tags: web, dns, hosting

I have registed a domain name with Dreamhost and have uploaded my website files onto my webspace. I have some questions regading DNS.

- Do my DNS records reside on the Dreamhost server?
- Are there any benefits to moving the DNS records to anpother location?

When I visit my URL xxxxx.com, does the dns iterative query
- hit the root servers.
- followed by the TLD server.
- followed by the server hosting my domain (dreamhost servers)

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS entries will be with Dreamhost. Most probably dns is managed from the same server.

Regarding DNS record migration, some hosting providers help you to manage your DNS entries from your hosting client area. Most probably, dns entries are managed by hosting provider. If you are able to manage from client area, it will be better option. I have also seen that many are cheap hosting providers, but have poor DNS servers.
In such cases also DNS migration will be good option

Answer (score 0):

The DNS directory is simply pointing to the Dreamhost server from the Root server managed by ICANN. So, Dreamhost is NOT hosting your domain it just owns the IP address that's behind xxxxxxx.com. I hope that helps!